# How to restrict user from extracting data in mongodb with only read access

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I have created role with read access and assign it to user. The user is able to extract data from MongoDB Compass who is having only read access. How I can stop extraction access of these role?

Comment: Simply revoke the read access. Your question does not make much sense. A read role grants permission to read data (what else?), so why do you want to restrict reading the data?

Comment: Extraction and reading are the same...